Can you make 39 using the numbers 5 4 3 2 1 in that order?
Is it mathematically possible to show by some creative way that when you combine the digits 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 in that order using operators (+, -, x, integer division/ floating point division(//) or modulus(%)) that you will or will not get the number 39?
By adding other operators it's possible:

Borrowing a principle from computer science called concatenation: (5 cat 4) = 54 / 3 = 18 + (2 cat 1) = 21 gives you 39.
Inverse exponentiation (eg. 4 inv exp with 2 is the square root of 4=2): A solution comes up 4^3=64 inv exp with 2 gives you 8. 5*8 = 40-1 = 39


Hi!  What's "integer division" as opposed to "division"?  Does it mean 3/2 = 1 (i.e. ignore the remainder)?

Did you come up with this puzzle yourself?

yeah msh210 you are right

I modified an existing puzzle

Why are there so many downvotes?

If allowed to use the factorial operator:

 $(5 * 4! - 3) / (2 + 1)$

If allowed to use the $\sqrt{x}$ operator:

 $(5 * \sqrt{4} + 3) * (2 + 1)$

I couldn't find a way to do it with just + - * / %.

Thanks a lot for the lucid answer @JS1

Depending on what the meaning of division is:
regular division

 5 x 43/2 - 1

or
division rounds down

 5 x -4 x (-3/2) - 1


Please check the math of your second answer Albert.

Please note the edits to my question if you are interested in a given it try. Also I am interested in a genius mathematically elegant answer. Not an exhaustive search.

YOU LITERALLY COPIED MY ANSWER @AlbertLang

@alex The second answer is perfectly fine, since -1.5 rounded down (i.e. in the negative direction on the number line) becomes -2. The first answer is not quite a copy of yours since it uses division (in the exponent) and not the "inverse exponentiation" operation, but since you removed exponentiation from the list of allowed operations, it is no longer a valid solution regardless.

@alex please do not SHOUT. They have not "literally copied your answer". You haven't posted an answer, except to show how it can be done with different rules.

@WeatherVane I am not lying. They have in their 1st answer. Their second answer is wrong anyway.

Excuse me, I can't see this in your question. It is not LITERALLY COPIED. And as explained the second is not wrong.

IT LITERALLY IS..WHY CAN"T YOU COMPARE MY SOLUTION AND HIS CAREFULLY @WeatherVane I LITERALLY SAID THIS IN WORDS 5 x 43/2 - 1

The question has become a 'shifting sand' question, having removed exponentiation since this answer was posted.

@alex You described a solution involving exponentiation and the extra operation of inverse exponentiation. The above answer shows that the inverse exponentiation operation is not needed in the set of rules because you can simply use division instead. You then removed exponentiation altogether, invalidating this answer. I find it a bit strange that you then accept the other answer that also includes various other operations that you did not ask for.

@JaapScherphuis The person who wrote this answer literally copied me . I will appeal to the committee to get it removed. Also why the hell can't anyone see that the answer is like wrong..I'm leaving this stupid exchange full of idiots

As for the integer division answer, this is how integer division works on negative numbers in most programming languages.
